# взаимодействие php и python

Tags: php, python

Необходимо в скрипте python обрабатывать данные, которые пользователь вводит в php форму. То есть, по сути в скрипте python  нужно чем-то заменить input, чтобы в обрботку шли введенные в php форму данные,а потом результат обратботки передавался обратно в php либо в БД... Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Подскажите , как быть

Comment: Что значит `php форма?`

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч обычная HTML-форма. Без php-то она мало полезна)

Comment: Нет такого понятия как `php форма`, есть язык который эту форму обрабатывает, это может быть как php так и любой другой ЯП., и на форму это не как не влияет, максимум что вы можете так это сверстать ее с помощью php, но от этого суть ее не изменится и обрабатывать полученные с нее данные может любой ЯП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть доступ к командной строке, то можно вызвать `shell_exec('python script.py -arg1=foo -arg2=bar');`

Comment: в том ведь и дело, что у пользователя будет только веб-страница с формой, куда ввести можно даныые

Comment: Ну это у пользователя. А на PHP-форму можно повесить обработчик: `<form action="action.php">`, где содержимое файла `action.php` выглядит примерно следующим образом: `$res = shell_exec('python script.py -arg1=foo -arg2=bar');`. В таком случае, python-скрипт должен возвращать данные просто в командную строку. Я, например, использовал бы JSON-формат для этих целей

Comment: Лучше сразу поставить обработчик формы на питоновский скрипт (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070373/how-to-send-and-receive-http-post-requests-in-python) если веб-сервер имеет его handler.

Answer (score 3):

Форма по определению **HTML**. То что она сгенерированна **php** скриптом значения не имеет.

Есть несколько способов решить данную проблему.

1. Если **python** доступен через **web** сервер отправить `post/get/put/delete` ... запрос напрямую данному скрипту.
2. Как посоветовал @Александр Чи. **PHP** может вызывать команды на прямую через `shell_exec/exec/system/passthru`... Читайте документацию выбирайте подходящую.
3. Сделайте очередь обработки. **PHP** будет складывать задания а **Python** их будет выполнять. Можно сделать *pull* систему через DB/файловую систему(e.g: **Zend Queue**).  Или *push* систему через брокера (**ZeroMQ, RabitMQ, Gearman** ...)